# Rearrange data from single observation to many

Tags: r, split

I've a text file in following form:

```
x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3
```

If I import it with `read.csv` I've a single observation with nine variables (in the example, the number of triplets in real file is unknown).

I want to rearrange data in order to have many observation with three variables:

```
x1 y1 z1
x2 y2 z2
x3 y3 z3
```

So I can perform operations on each triplet.

For example I want to transform this

```
fileData <- read.table(text = "1 2 3 10 20 30 100 200 300")

> fileData
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6  V7  V8  V9
1  1  2  3 10 20 30 100 200 300
```

to this:

```
> fileData
   V1  V2  V3
1   1   2   3
2  10  20  30
3 100 200 300
```

How can I split it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what your actual goal is but using base R:

```
data.frame(matrix(fileData, ncol = 3, byrow = T))
```

This should get what you want

```
   X1  X2  X3
1   1   2   3
2  10  20  30
3 100 200 300
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

akash gave a great answer but it may not work if you have mixed data types (numeric and character) because the matrix will force everything to be one type.  An alternative is something like the following where we `lapply` across an index based on the number of columns desired.

```
fileData <- read.table(text = "m 2 3 a 20 30 cat 200 300")
rows = lapply(seq(3,ncol(fileData),by=3),
       function(x){
         range = paste("V",(x-2):x,sep="")
         output = fileData[,range]
         names(output) = c("x","y","z")
         return(output)
       })
do.call(rbind,rows)
#>     x   y   z
#> 1   m   2   3
#> 2   a  20  30
#> 3 cat 200 300
```

Comment: Thanks. In my specific case data are not mixed.

Comment: That's fine, I was trying to provide a more general purpose solution in case someone comes across this question in the future :)